# Comparison of two files in python

Tags: python

I've two text files and contains data like this

I WANT this to be done in hadoop. Can any one suggest me the way ?
    textfile1 --> 1 goerge hyder
                  2 ganesh singapore

```
textfile2 --> 1 goergy hydel
              2 ganest singapore
```

It has to do comparission coulmn by column and character by character so after comparission it should give report as

```
column_name source destiny mismatch
      xxx    george georgy y
             ganesh ganest h
             hyder  hydel  r
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Maybe `difflib` will help. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('textfile1.txt', 'a').readlines()
for n in f:
    text1 = n.rstrip()
n = open('textfile2.txt', 'a').readlines()
for l in n:
    text2 = l.rstrip()
if text1 == text2:
   print("It Is the Same Thing")
   report = open('report.txt')
   report.write('It is The Same Thing with the text 1 and 2')
   report.write('\n')
else:
   print("it Is Not The Same Thing")
   report = open('report.txt')
   report.write('It is Not The Same Thign With the text 1 and 2')
   report.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(textfile1,"r") as f1:
    with open(textfile2,"r") as f2:

        words1 = f1.read().split(" ")
        words2 = f2.read().split(" ")


        #considering f1 and f2 have the same number of words
        for i in range(len(words1)):

            if words1[i] != words2[i]:

                for j in range(len(words1[i])):

                    if words1[i][j] != words2[i][j]:

                        print(words1[i],words2[i],words2[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Seer.The](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6120211/seer-the) mentioned above, you can use `difflib`.

```
import difflib

# Read the files
f = open('textfile1.txt', 'r').readlines()
list1 = []
for n in f:
    text = n.rstrip().split(" ")
    list1.append(text)


f = open('textfile2.txt', 'r').readlines()
list2 = []
for n in f:
    text = n.rstrip().split(" ")
    list2.append(text)

# Get the output
for ii in range(len(list1)):
    for jj in range(len(list1[0])):
        output_list = [li[-1] 
                       for li in list(difflib.ndiff(list1[ii][jj], list2[ii][jj]))
                       if "-" in li]
        if output_list == []:
            output_list = ["no difference"]
        print "{} {} {}".format(list1[ii][jj], list2[ii][jj], output_list[0])
```

The output should look like:

```
goerge goergy e
hyder hydel r
ganesh ganest h
singapore singapore no difference
```